# VBA Excel Macro .copy and paste destination Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I wish I could give my client the security to run the Control + C macro and copy its ROW to the clipboard, and clearly paste it with Control + V, leaving the security of the sheet.

```py
Sub Copyfile()

 Call Disable 

  Selection.Copy

  Call Activate

End Sub

Sub PasteRows()

 Call Disable

  ActiveCell.Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Selection

    Call Activate


End Sub

A 1004 error has occurred at runtime
Error in the Paste method of the Worksheet class
**ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Selection**
```

I throw the error, that I am trying 
to paste in a merged cell, and it is 
correct this is necessary for my project. –   
In the case that I put everything inside me, the same macro happens.

```
Sub PasteRows() 
Selection.Copy 
Call Disable
Selection.Copy 
ActiveCell.Select 
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Selection 

Call Activate 

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just `copy` in the same sub that's pasting it? That might be causing an issue. If you just do `Selection.Copy` right before your `.Paste` line, do you still get an error?

Comment: I just added the lines you can check them

Comment: Nowhere in the code does it paste rows. And I am still confused after that because this code copies a selection, then immediately pastes the selection into the active cells (which should be the same cells because nothing has happened to change the selection). And then the code checks the value of a specific cell that probably has nothing to do with the selection and probably has not changed.

Comment: However, your issue is most likely to be that `Selection` is not a valid destination. `Selection` is a generic object that is not strongly typed and can mean many things in different contexts.

Comment: I just deleted those parts of the code, which you indicate, if it is true that part should not be pasted here, the context is as follows select with the Mouse a row press Control + C and place in the target cell and press control + V